# NS-3 Compiling Error

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, ns-3

I am trying to use [NS-3.15](http://www.nsnam.org/ns-3-15) on MAC Mountain Lion but when I compile I get the following errors:

```
source not found: 'model/itu-r-1411-nlos-over-rooftop-propagation-loss-model.cc' in bld(features=['cxx', 'cxxshlib', 'ns3module'], ns3_dir_location='src/propagation', pcfilegen=bld(features='ns3pcfile', idx=2, meths=[], prec=defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), _name='', source='', module='ns3-propagation', mappings={}, path=/Users/user/Desktop/nsam.org/ns-allinone-3.15/ns-3.15/src/propagation, target='') in /Users/user/Desktop/nsam.org/ns-allinone-3.15/ns-3.15/src/propagation, use=['ns3-network', 'ns3-mobility'], mappings={}, uselib='', meths=['set_macosx_deployment_target', '_add_test_code', 'apply_bundle', 'process_rule', 'process_source', 'apply_link', 'apply_objdeps', 'apply_uselib_local', 'process_use', 'propagate_uselib_vars', 'apply_incpaths', 'apply_implib', 'apply_vnum'], prec=defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), source=['model/propagation-delay-model.cc', 'model/propagation-loss-model.cc', 'model/jakes-propagation-loss-model.cc', 'model/jakes-process.cc', 'model/cost231-propagation-loss-model.cc', 'model/okumura-hata-propagation-loss-model.cc', 'model/itu-r-1411-los-propagation-loss-model.cc', 'model/itu-r-1411-nlos-over-rooftop-propagation-loss-model.cc', 'model/kun-2600-mhz-propagation-loss-model.cc'], test=False, is_ns3_module=True, install_path='${LIBDIR}', module_deps=['network', 'mobility'], includes='.', dependencies=['network', 'mobility'], path=/Users/user/Desktop/nsam.org/ns-allinone-3.15/ns-3.15/src/propagation, vnum=None, posted=True, is_static=False, target='../../ns3.15-propagation-debug', idx=1, _name='ns3-propagation') in /Users/user/Desktop/nsam.org/ns-allinone-3.15/ns-3.15/src/propagation
```

If I understand correctly I think this means it can't find those dependencies but I haven't been able to figure out how to add them or where should they even be, could anyone help me out? I am following [this tutorial](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.15/tutorial/ns-3-tutorial.pdf).

I understand this is not a programming question itself but I haven't figured out where to ask so if you know a better place please let me know.

Comment: Can you describe what steps you followed exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Your installation are not clean. 
Try to follow this installation tutorial http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/index.php/Installation

Fastest response place to asking NS3 problem are on their NS3 User Group Mailing List https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ns-3-users